# Custom Settings data is not added to package. Any thoughts?

Tags: customsetting, package

i have created few custom settings and loaded them with data and i added the custom setting to an unmanagaed package. While deploying the package in another org i saw the custom settings did not have values except the structure. Any thoughts? How can i get the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom Settings are just like any sObejct, if you want the data be included you must have a post script to insert the records into the custom settings.
for more info : [Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_unmanaged_components.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Value entered in custom setting doesn't available in client organizations. Either you have to create them manually or by post-install script. Custom-setting are just like custom objects.

Also you can add check in code if value exist then just use them otherwise insert default values.